# Problema com o uso do else

Tags: php, html, mysql

Boa noite, estou com problema que é o seguinte, na página pedidos caso o usuário tenha 1 pedido ou mais ele exibe o pedido, caso o usuário não tenha nenhum pedido aparece a mensagem "Você não possui nenhum pedido", ou pelo menos deveria aparecer.Com o código que tenho até o momento, quando o usuário tem algum pedido aparece normalmente, mais quando ele ainda não fez nenhum pedido, não aparece a mensagem. Vou deixar meu código abaixo.

```html
  $result=$conn->query($comando);
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $comando);
if (count($result)>0){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ ?>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row"><?= $row['order_id'] ?></th>
            <td><?= $row['order_date'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $row['order_name'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $row['order_endereco'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $row['order_numero'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $row['order_referencia'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $row['situacao'] ?></td>
        </tr>
<?php } }else{ ?>
<div class="text-center">Você não possui nenhum pedido</div>
<?php  } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso é porque `$result` não é um array, ele é um objeto do tipo [mysqli_result](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php), então não faz sentido utilizar `count($result)` para verificar se ele encontrou resultado ou não.

Você deveria estar verificando se a propriedade `num_rows` é diferente de 0, ou seja

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // Encontrou um ou mais resultados
} else {
  // Não encontrou resultados
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $comando))
{
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ ?>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row"><?= $row['order_id'] ?></th>
            <td><?= $row['order_date'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $row['order_name'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $row['order_endereco'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $row['order_numero'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $row['order_referencia'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $row['situacao'] ?></td>
        </tr>
<?php } }else { ?>
<div class="text-center">Você não possui nenhum pedido</div>
<?php  } ?>
```